# css-grid responsive table with collapsing columns no-JS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I managed to create a responsive table with collapsing columns using css-grid (no JS).

I use 2 CSS vars to control the display: --data-cols and --show-cols.

I.e. if --data-cols: 3 but --show-cols: 2, then the grid only has 2 columns, but the data still has 3.  This would normally cause the data to wrap around to the next row.  So we want css-grid to hide the 3rd column, not just skip it.

The trick was to create an invisible row which spans all 3 data-cols.  This seems to force the grid to have 3 columns. And the 3rd column has a width of 0 because grid-auto-columns: 0;

This seems to work in my testing.  But it feels like a hack.  Is there a better way (without JS)?

```css
.itemTable {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  --show-cols: 1;
}

.itemTable:not(.data1cols) {
  --show-cols: 2;
}

.itemTable.data1cols {
  --data-cols: 1;
}

.itemTable.data2cols {
  --data-cols: 2;
}

.itemTable.data3cols {
  --data-cols: 3;
}

.itemTable.data4cols {
  --data-cols: 4;
}

.itemTable table {
  margin: 6px;
  border-spacing: 0 4px;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* https://www.meltajon.com/dev/how-to-use-supports-display-contents-feature-query-in-safari */

@supports (display: contents) and (caret-color: red) {
  .itemTable table {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--show-cols), auto);
    grid-auto-columns: 0;
  }
  .itemTable thead,
  .itemTable tbody,
  .itemTable tfoot,
  .itemTable tr {
    display: contents;
  }
}

.itemTable thead>tr>th {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 18px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.itemTable td {
  background-color: #555555;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.itemTable tr * {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: #9f9697;
}

.itemTable a {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.itemTable .hidden-span-row>td {
  grid-column: 1 / span var(--data-cols);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Mobile-first: Small tablet and larger */

@media all and (min-width: 479px) {
  /* workaround browser not support min() */
  .itemTable:not(.data2cols):not(.data1cols) {
    --show-cols: 3;
  }
}


/* Mobile-first: Tablet and larger */

@media all and (min-width: 700px) {
  .itemTable table {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--data-cols), auto);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="itemTable data3cols">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="hidden-span-row">
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: why use html table and declare it as css-grid? The whole reason to use css-grid is not to use html tables for design layouts. You can use `:nth-child(3n + 3)` selector to select all columns in the 3rd column and hide them.

Comment: Thanks for looking @tacoshy I figured I'm progressively enhancing a table, so the fallback is still a working table.  The nth-child() selector doesn't work with css vars, so how would I use it to hide an unknown number of data-cols?

Comment: Well, shoot.  I realized my table is not collapsing in MS Edge.  Who uses that browser anyway?

Answer (score 1):

In this example I use a real css-grid. Simple HTML structure with only the grid cells. Then I use:

`.grid-table > div:nth-child(3n + 1) { grid-column: 1 / 2; }` to make sure that all 1st column cells stay in the first column and the same with the 2nd row (`:nth-child(3n + 2)`). If you use the same selector we can select all 3rd column elements and simply use `display: none;` to hide them.

In combination with `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content);` they appear collapsed.

```css
.grid-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  width: min-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-table > div {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
}

.grid-table > div:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.grid-table > div:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.grid-table > div:nth-child(3n + 3) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid-table">
  <div>Column 1</div>
  <div>Column 2</div>
  <div>Column 3</div>
  <div>data</div>
  <div>data</div>
  <div>data</div>
  <div>data</div>
  <div>data</div>
  <div>data</div>
</section>
```

Comment: This seems like the common approach I have seen.  But can you make this responsive so that only the columns that would fit in the viewport are shown?  Also I would like to have the CSS reusable for tables with any number of columns.